# DO to Azure, site to site VPN, can my client private IP send the traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan

Using Strongswan IPSEC

eth0 IP is xx.xx.129.177 (which is our public IP and the one currently sending requests)
the gate way to eth0 is xx.xx.128.1

eth0:1 IP is 10.16.0.24/16 - Client expects this address to deliver TCP requests and make the SQL connection, is this the private IP address of eth0? And can I route traffic to use this??

I'm not sure how to route traffic through eth0:1 and tbh I'm not sure if I'm thinking about routing correctly with the firewall rules either, I've tried to config a vti but had no luck so far.

I've manufactured IP addresses but anyway, the tunnel is established and active

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.0-131-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 4 minutes, since Nov 09 09:23:28 2022
  malloc: sbrk 3084288, mmap 0, used 1178368, free 1905920
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 1
  loaded plugins: charon test-vectors ldap pkcs11 tpm aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent chapoly xcbc cmac h>
Listening IP addresses:
  xx.xx.129.177
  10.16.0.24
  ----------IPv6 addr
 10.106.0.19
Connections:
   ikev2-vpn:  xx.xx.129.177...xx.xx.xx.xx  IKEv2, dpddelay=45s
   ikev2-vpn:   local:  [xx.xx.129.177] uses pre-shared key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:   remote: [xx.xx.xx.xx] uses pre-shared key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:   child:  0.0.0.0/0 === 0.0.0.0/0 TUNNEL, dpdaction=clear
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   ikev2-vpn[3]: ESTABLISHED 103 seconds ago, xx.xx.129.177[xx.xx.129.177]...xx.xx.xx.xx[xx.xx.xx.xx]
   ikev2-vpn[3]: IKEv2 SPIs: e230895c46f01cf6_i* c0858ade8e997bdc_r, rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn[3]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/MODP_2048_256
   ikev2-vpn{2}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP in UDP SPIs: c9c519ad_i de8973aa_o
   ikev2-vpn{2}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128, 132 bytes_i (3 pkts, 2s ago), 10601 bytes_o (37 pkts, 17s ago), rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn{2}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Unclear. Title makes little sense.

Comment: Digital ocean vpc to Azure vpc, site to site vpn, my side (client side) private IP is expected to be seen sending the TCP requests